# Type Conversion Causing an Error

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio-2012, types, vsto

the following code is causing an error, I understand why but I dont know how to fix it:

```
public static Excel.Application CurrentApplication = new Excel.Application();
CurrentApplication.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
```

How do I explicitly change the type of Cursors.Default?

Comment: What error? One thing is clear you need to wrap `CurrentApplication.Cursor = Cursors.Default;` inside a method.

Comment: Yeah, it is wrapped inside a method.

Comment: The error is: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Windows.Forms.Cursor' to 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XIMousePointer'

Answer (score 2):

Cursors.Default is a windows forms cursor. You have to provide an excel XlMousePointer:

```
public enum XlMousePointer
{
    xlDefault = -4143,
    xlNorthwestArrow = 1,
    xlWait = 2,
    xlIBeam = 3,
}
```

So this works:
    (using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;)

```
CurrentApplication.Cursor = Excel.XlMousePointer.xlDefault;
```

Comment: oh cool. thanks so much. What if I want to assign my own custom cursor.cur file?

Comment: Or better yet, is there any way to convert one of the system.windows.forms.cursors images to x1 so that I can assign it here?